# ElasticSearch Nested Object Mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nested, spring-data-elasticsearch

> ```
> I have created following mapping for in ElasticSearch and same is created. But when I add documents to this type, my nested field type
> ```
>
> changes to normal. So when I execute query on nested object fields,it
>   shows unexpected results while on rest of the fields results are as
>   expected. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. There must be something
>   I am missing while creating nested object mapping.

```
request_body = {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "standard": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase", "stop"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "mappings" : {
      "userdetails" : {
        "properties" : {
          "accountType" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "addressLineOne" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "addressLineTwo" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "alternateEmailId" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
           "archiveId" : {
            "type" : "string"
           },
          "blockedEmployerId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "cityId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "country" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "coverPicUrl" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "currentEmployer" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "currentPackageCurrencyId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "currentPackageUnit" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "currentSalaryPackage" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "currentlocation" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "designation" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "emailId" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "employmentDetail" : {
    "type":"nested",
            "properties" : {
              "companyName" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "designation" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "durationEndMonth" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "durationEndYear" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "durationStartMonth" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "durationStartYear" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "employmentStatus" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "isCurrent" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "jobProfile" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "location" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "timeDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "userId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "examscores" : {
    "type":"nested",
            "properties" : {
              "attemptedCount" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "candidateId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "examDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "examId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "examScoreDetailId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "examTotalScore" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "examType" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "katExamEventId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "rightAttempted" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "rptVisStatus" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "scorePercent" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "timeDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "token" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "totalQuestion" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "totalScore" : {
                "type" : "double"
              }
            }
          },
          "experienceInMonths" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "experienceInYears" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "firstName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "gender" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "hQPS" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "higestQualInstitute" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "higestQualInstituteLoc" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "higestQualPassingYear" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "higestQualPercentCgpa" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "higestQualification" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "highestQualSpecialization" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "highestQualificationStream" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "industryDomain" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "keySkills" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "lastLoginDate" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "lastName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "lastUpdateDate" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "locationName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "maritalStatus" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "mobileNumber" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "password" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "paswdChangedDate" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "phoneNumber" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "preferredLocations" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "profileImageUrl" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "profileSummary" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "projectdetail" : {
    "type":"nested",
            "properties" : {
              "clientName" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "designation" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "durationEndMonth" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "durationEndYear" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "durationStartMonth" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "durationStartYear" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "employmentNature" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "location" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "rolesResponsibilities" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "skillsUsed" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "teamSize" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "timeDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "title" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "userId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "qualification" : {
    "type":"nested",
            "properties" : {
              "id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "institute" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "isPrimary" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "passingYear" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "percentageCgpa" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "qualification" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "specialization" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "timeDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "userId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "registrationDate" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "resumeContentType" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "resumeTitle" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "s3DocKey" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "s3HtmlKey" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "sectionalscores" : {
    "type":"nested",
            "properties" : {
              "attemptedCount" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "candidateId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "examScoreId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "examTime" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "examTitleId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "katExamId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "katScoreId" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "rightAttempted" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "score" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "scorePercent" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "timeDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "totalQuestion" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "totalScore" : {
                "type" : "double"
              }
            }
          },
          "stateId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "timeDate" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "userId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "uuid" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "videoIntroType" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "videoIntroUrl" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "videoProfileTimeDate" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
           "videoProfileUrl" : {
            "type" : "string"
           },
           "videoProfileVisibility" : {
             "type" : "long"
           },
          "workStatusForOtherCountries" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "workStatusForUS" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "xIIPS" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "xIIPassingYear" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "xIIPercentageCgpa" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "xPS" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "xPassingYear" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "xPercentageCgpa" : {
            "type" : "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

print("creating 'example_index' index...")

res = es1.indices.create(index = 'no-one', body = request_body)
```

**After creating index using above code, I added the data into this index using following code.**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
import MySQLdb
import json
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='xxxx',

                                passwd='xxxx',
                                db='xxxxx'
                                )

cursor_mysql = db.cursor()

cursor_mysql.execute("select * from USER ")
userTable = cursor_mysql.fetchall()
cursor_mysql.execute("select * from qualificationmapping")
secondaryQualification = cursor_mysql.fetchall()
cursor_mysql.execute("select * from examscoredetail")
examscore = cursor_mysql.fetchall()
cursor_mysql.execute("select * from katsectionalscore")
sectionalScore = cursor_mysql.fetchall()
cursor_mysql.execute("select * from projectexperiencedetails")
proejctDetails = cursor_mysql.fetchall()
cursor_mysql.execute("select * from useremploymentdetails")
employmentDetails = cursor_mysql.fetchall()

data = []
listSecondaryQualification=[]
listExamScores=[]
listSectionalScores=[]
listProjectDetails=[]
listEmploymentDetails=[]
# jsonSecondaryQualification = ''
# jsonExamScores = ''
# jsonSectionalScores = ''
# jsonProjectDetails = ''
# jsonEmploymentDetails = ''
# proejctdetail = {}
# qualification = {}
sectionalscores = {}
indexdata={}
# examscores = {}
# employmentDetail = {}
es1 = Elasticsearch()
# es1.create(index="xxxxx", doc_type='xxxx', body=indexdata)


count = 0

for userid in userTable:
    count+=1
    indexdata = {
        "_index": "xxxxx",
        "_type": "xxxxx",
        "_id": userid[0]
    }
    for item in userTable:
        if userid[0]== item[0]:
            userdata = {
                'userId': item[0],
                'accountType': item[1],
                'addressLineOne': item[2],
                'addressLineTwo': item[3],
                'alternateEmailId': item[4],
                'archiveId':item[5],
                'blockedEmployerId': item[6],
                'cityId': item[7],
                'classXIISchool': item[8],
                'classXSchool': item[9],
                'country': item[10],
                'coverPicUrl': item[11],
                'currentEmployer': item[12],
                'currentPackageCurrencyId': item[13],
                'currentPackageUnit': item[14],
                'currentSalaryPackage': item[15],
                'currentlocation': item[16],
                'designation': item[17],
                'emailId': item[19],
                'experienceInMonths': item[20],
                'experienceInYears': item[21],
                'firstName': item[22],
                'gender': item[23],
                'hQPS': item[24],
                'higestQualInstitute': item[25],
                'higestQualInstituteLoc': item[26],
                'higestQualPassingYear': item[27],
                'higestQualPercentCgpa': item[28],
                'higestQualification': item[29],
                'highestQualSpecialization': item[30],
                'highestQualificationStream': item[31],
                'industryDomain': item[32],
                'keySkills': item[33],
                'lastLoginDate': str(item[34]),
                'lastName': item[35],
                'lastUpdateDate': str(item[36]),
                'locationName': item[37],
                'maritalStatus': item[38],
                'middleName': item[39],
                'mobileNumber': item[40],
                'password': item[41],
                'paswdChangedDate': item[42],
                'phoneNumber': item[43],
                'preferredLocations': item[44],
                'previousEmployer': item[45],
                'profileImageUrl': item[46],
                'profileSummary': item[47],
                'registrationDate': str(item[48]),
                'resumeContentType': item[49],
                'resumeTitle': item[50],
                's3DocKey': item[51],
                's3HtmlKey': item[52],
                'stateId': item[53],
                'status': item[54],
                'timeDate': str(item[55]),
                'uuid': item[56],
                'videoIntroType': item[57],
                'videoIntroUrl': item[58],
                'videoProfileTimeDate': item[59],
                'videoProfileUrl': item[60],
                'videoProfileVisibility': item[61],
                'workStatusForOtherCountries': item[62],
                'workStatusForUS': item[63],
                'xIIPS': item[64],
                'xIIPassingYear': item[65],
                'xIIPercentageCgpa': item[66],
                'xPS': item[67],
                'xPassingYear': item[68],
                'xPercentageCgpa': item[69]
            }

    for quid in secondaryQualification:
        if userid[0]== quid[8]:
            indQualification = {
                'id': quid[0],
                'institute': quid[1],
                'isPrimary': quid[2],
                'passingYear': quid[3],
                'percentageCgpa': quid[4],
                'qualification': quid[5],
                'specialization': quid[6],
                'timeDate': str(quid[7]),
                'userId': quid[8]
            }
            listSecondaryQualification.append(indQualification)
            # qualification[quid[0]] = indQualification
            # print(qualification)
    for esdid in examscore:
        if userid[0]== esdid[2]:
            indExamscores = {
                'examScoreDetailId': esdid[0],
                'attemptedCount': esdid[1],
                'candidateId': esdid[2],
                'examDate': esdid[3],
                'examId': esdid[4],
                'examTotalScore': esdid[5],
                'examType': esdid[6],
                'katExamEventId': esdid[7],
                'rightAttempted': esdid[8],
                'rptVisStatus': esdid[9],
                'scorePercent': esdid[10],
                'timeDate': str(esdid[11]),
                'token': esdid[12],
                'totalQuestion': esdid[13],
                'totalScore': esdid[14]
            }
            listExamScores.append(indExamscores)
            # examscores[esdid[0]]=indExamscores
            # print(examscores)
    for scid in sectionalScore:
        if userid[0]== scid[2]:
            indSectionalscores = {
                'katScoreId': scid[0],
                'attemptedCount': scid[1],
                'candidateId': scid[2],
                'examScoreId': scid[3],
                'examTime': scid[4],
                'examTitleId': scid[5],
                'katExamId': scid[6],
                'rightAttempted': scid[7],
                'score': scid[8],
                'scorePercent': scid[9],
                'scoreS3Key': scid[10],
                'timeDate': str(scid[11]),
                'totalQuestion': scid[12],
                'totalScore': scid[13]
            }
            listSectionalScores.append(indSectionalscores)
            # sectionalscores[scid[0]]=indSectionalscores
            # print(sectionalscores)
    for prid in proejctDetails:
        if userid[0] == prid[16]:
            indvidualProjectdetail = {
                'id': prid[0],
                'clientName': prid[1],
                'designation': prid[2],
                'durationEndMonth': prid[3],
                'durationEndYear': prid[4],
                'durationStartMonth': prid[5],
                'durationStartYear': prid[6],
                'employmentNature': prid[7],
                'location': prid[8],
                'projectDetails': prid[9],
                'rolesResponsibilities': prid[10],
                'site': prid[11],
                'skillsUsed': prid[12],
                'teamSize': prid[13],
                'timeDate': str(prid[14]),
                'title': prid[15],
                'userId': prid[16]
            }
            listProjectDetails.append(indvidualProjectdetail)
            # proejctdetail[prid[0]]=indvidualProjectdetail
            # print(proejctdetail)
    for userempid in employmentDetails:
        if userid[0]==userempid[12]:
            indEmploymentDetail = {
                'id': userempid[0],
                'companyName': userempid[1],
                'designation': userempid[2],
                'durationEndMonth': userempid[3],
                'durationEndYear': userempid[4],
                'durationStartMonth': userempid[5],
                'durationStartYear': userempid[6],
                'employmentStatus': userempid[7],
                'isCurrent': userempid[8],
                'jobProfile': userempid[9],
                'location': userempid[10],
                'timeDate': str(userempid[11]),
                'userId': userempid[12]
            }
            listEmploymentDetails.append(indEmploymentDetail)
            # employmentDetail[userempid[0]]=indEmploymentDetail
            # print(employmentDetail)





    # for item in listSecondaryQualification:
    #     jsonSecondaryQualification += json.dumps(item) + ','
    # jsonSecondaryQualification = jsonSecondaryQualification[:-1]
    #
    # for item in listEmploymentDetails:
    #     jsonEmploymentDetails+=json.dumps(item)+','
    # jsonEmploymentDetails = jsonEmploymentDetails[:-1]
    #
    # for item in listExamScores:
    #     jsonExamScores+=json.dumps(item)+','
    # jsonExamScores = jsonExamScores[:-1]
    #
    # for item in listProjectDetails:
    #     jsonProjectDetails+=json.dumps(item)+','
    # jsonProjectDetails=jsonProjectDetails[:-1]
    #
    # for item in listSectionalScores:
    #     jsonSectionalScores+=json.dumps(item)+','
    # jsonSectionalScores=jsonSectionalScores[:-1]

    userdata['qualification'] = listSecondaryQualification
    userdata['examscores'] = listExamScores
    userdata['sectionalscores'] = listSectionalScores
    userdata['projectdetail'] = listProjectDetails
    userdata['employmentDetail'] = listEmploymentDetails
    indexdata["_source"] = userdata
    # doc['doc'] = indexdata
    data.append(indexdata)
    # print(data)
    # break


    #Flusing All lists
    listSecondaryQualification = []
    listExamScores = []
    listSectionalScores = []
    listProjectDetails = []
    listEmploymentDetails = []
    # jsonSecondaryQualification = ''
    # jsonExamScores = ''
    # jsonSectionalScores = ''
    # jsonProjectDetails = ''
    # jsonEmploymentDetails = ''
    # proejctdetail = {}
    # qualification = {}
    # sectionalscores = {}
    # examscores = {}
    # employmentDetail = {}

    # print("Document Inserted Successfully")
    if (count==2000):
        break
    print('On my way')
helpers.bulk(es1, data)
print("bulk import done")
```

Comment: Note that `not_analysed` should be `not_analyzed` with a `z` not an `s`. Fix your mapping, wipe your index and try again, please.

Comment: I have fixed the required changes but the problem regarding that still persists.

Comment: Can you show how you create your index (i.e. what command are you using) and how you index a document? After creating your index, have you verified that your mapping was installed properly? It is not possible to change a nested object to a normal one once the index/mapping has been created, some something is wrong in your creation sequence.

Comment: I am creating this mapping using python. I am attaching that code in the question. I checked it after creating and mapping is of nested type as I require. But after adding data, nested field changes to normal, when I used nested query ,it shows an error that field is not nested type.

Comment: Please show a complete sequence of what you're doing so we can better reproduce/understand.

Comment: I shared the code in which index is created. I am also sharing the code for adding data to elasticsearch in this index.

Comment: Can you show the `_index` and `_type` information you put into `indexdata`?

Comment: Hi Val, thanks for the help. Your statement that mapping cannot be changed solved my problem. :)

Comment: How did you solve the issue? For the benefit of others with a similar problem...

Comment: I was giving different Document type to the one I gave while creating the mapping. It was a silly mistake and then your comment brought me the epiphany and solved my problem.

Comment: Correct, I was going to suggest that you were indexing documents into the wrong type. Good catch!!